# Node js url is working only on private window in React application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have an application built with reactjs with node js backend by using **Create React App** library.
in Nodejs-server.js I have the following code structure.

```js
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import visitors from './routes/visitors';
import { cronNotification } from './cron/cron.js';

let app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '15mb' }))
app.use(cors())

app.use('/api/visitors', visitors)
app.use('/docs/visitorTickets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../docs/visitorTickets')));
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../assets/images')));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../build')));
app.get('/*', function (req, res, next) {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../build', 'index.html'));
});

app.use((req, res) => {
 res.status(404).json({
  errors: {
   global: "Page Not Found."
  }
 })
});

let port  = 8080
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Running on port:'+port));
cronNotification();
```

**In Visitor file I have following code**

```js
import express from 'express';
import QRCode from 'qrcode';
import pdf from 'html-pdf';

let router = express.Router();

router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
 res.json({ success: "test success page." })
});

router.get('/pdf', (req, res) => {
 let html = '<div>test value</div>';
 pdf.create(html).toStream((err, pdfStream) => {
    if (err) {   
      return res.sendStatus(500)
    } else {
      res.statusCode = 200             
      pdfStream.on('end', () => {
        return res.end()
      })
      pdfStream.pipe(res)
    }
  });
});

export default router;
```

This code working perfect with front end react app by using **http://localhost:3000/test**.
It gets the result via API from axios library from react action page.
In developr tool network -> result shows: **success: "test success page."**

**Now the issues is:**
When I access 
http://localhost:8080/api/visitors/pdf **OR**
http://localhost:8080/api/visitors/test
Directly in browser, It shows blank page (directly frot end source is appearing from console)
While access it from private window, It shows the result.
It tried it with diffrent browsers and diffrent computers but issue remain the same.
I am suspecting something wrong in this code

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../build')));
app.get('/*', function (req, res, next) {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../build', 'index.html'));
});
```

It is neglecting app.use path (app.use('/api/visitors', visitors))

Kindly help me out why this is working only in private browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long battle, I have fixed that issue by unregister react's **registerServiceWorker**

```js
import { unregister } from './registerServiceWorker';
unregister();
```

Answer (score 0):

So, why you need to res.sendFile to send an html page ? Let try to use ejs or jade view engine and then : 
`app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    return res.render('../path_to_ejs_view_file');
});`

Or in your case maybe call `next()` function can solve problem:

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res, next) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../build', 'index.html'));
next();
});
```

By the way, I have an project like you. Use Nodejs for api and Reacjs for SPA here: https://github.com/dangminhtruong/havana hope it useful

Comment: I tried this but still not working.. but working in private window.

Comment: is there any header to be modified in node js server page to clear any cache?